# Stored XSS - Salesforce security check ( AngularJS) error

Tags: apex, visualforce, security-review, security-scanner

I am getting an error while security check
Category : cross-site scripting , Stored XSS  for below

**$scope.nameMap = {!nameMap};**

For javaScript we have some encoding methos but i didn't found such for angularJS. Please help.

angular script as below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap','ui.sortable'])    
          .controller('myTestCtrl', function($scope,$modal,$log,$filter,$interval) {
     $scope.nameMap = {!nameMap};
//...... other variables

 }
 </script>
```

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: I think issue here `$scope.nameMap = '{!nameMap}';` here `{!nameMap}` should be in single quote... and always use angular factory to share the value to controller..

Answer (score 3):

You will have to JSENCODE the getter variable ,

```
$scope.nameMap = '{!JSENCODE(nameMap)}' //If you are expecting just JSON string
```

If you need to further parse into JSON object use Javascript JSON.parse here

```
$scope.nameMap = JSON.parse('{!JSENCODE(nameMap)}');
```

Also try to keep all your script inside static resource as a security best practice and invoke from self executing anonymous function

Ideally for angular ,use [Javascript remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm) for getting data into $Scope or use [VFRemote Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects.htm)

Comment: I tried this, it wont support.

Comment: What does it not support ? You will need to encode and hence I would not go with getters and setters and instead use JS remoting for all calls to the backend

Comment: I tried using JSENCODE() method to encode angular scope variables. But nothing chnagiing.. Still same giving me security error..  for JAVASCRIPT, its supporting and i resolved error using this only. Not so lucky in case of AngularJS.

Comment: @Rahul Try to put all your JS in static resources and scan the VF .

Comment: Yes,  that's a cool escape :p will try this. Thanks!!

Comment: @MohithShrivastava This answer is *almost* correct. They're trying to get a native object, not a string, so this should be appropriate: `$scope.nameMap = JSON.parse('{!JSENCODE(nameMap)}');` This converts the string into the native object safely.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks .I thought they were using string there .Thanks again..Let me enhance the answer so others find it helpful